# When a person tags you in a photo, why does it not show up under photos of you?

Tags: facebook, facebook-photos

I was tagged in a photo (uploaded by another person) and when I go to my profile and click on *Photos*, it's not there. How can this be changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check if you have Tag Approvals enabled. If so, you would need to approve the tag for it to be shown on your timeline.
With the current Facebook settings for *share with Friends*, a photo should be visible to the owner, friends and friends of those tagged. Unless of-course the owner has chosen a different privacy setting.

Comment: No I don't have approve tags enabled for photos. I also notice there isn't an option to untag myself. Is it because the photo was directly uploaded to a group wall from a smartphone?